# Google Sheets with Apps Script - You do not have permission to perform that action

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I built an small application in Google Sheets. How do I share it correctly to allow other Google users to use it?

So I did the development under one of my gmail accounts and I shared it to another one of my gmail accounts. On the second gmail account, I copied it to my drive and attempted to use it. Then I got the error "You do not have permission to perform that action.".

How do I fix this?

Comment: what does your a-on exactly do, can you share code please?

Comment: It gets contact information from Google Contacts. I developed this for a client and now the client wants to use it.

Comment: don't you try to get contact from a not shared source?

Comment: I built it using a test gmail account. I want to use it on my account now, to load my contacts. But I cannot.

So I built it on beta.dtd@gmail.com, now I want to use it on will@daytodata.net.

I shared the projected + the sheet to will@daytodata.net. I open it and run it, then I get the error.

How do I properly deploy to allow others to use?

Comment: is the sheet shared with will@daytodata?

Comment: Yes. I even attempted to copy the code, create a blank sheet in will@daytodata, pasted the code in script editor and run it. Same error?

Comment: can you give us the exact error message with line and a piece of code please

Comment: The exact message is: You do not have permission to perform that action.

Can I share the sheet with you? The code is very long.

Comment: where do you get it on the user interface or in the script terminal can you `try``catch`code?

Comment: `18-09-06 16:28:26:774 PDT] Execution failed: You do not have permission to perform that action. (line 383, file "GoogleContactsProcessing") [0.092 seconds total runtime]`

line 383 has the following code:
`var MyContacts = ContactsApp.getContacts();`

Comment: can you add all these infos into your post please

Comment: If you are logged into two accounts at the same time, there is a bug that is causing an error.  Try logging out of all accounts and log back into the account that installed the add-on.  If that fixes the problem.  Another option is to open another window in the Chrome browser in incognito mode.  If this is not your problem, did you authorize the code to run by running a function from the code editor?

Comment: What do you mean by "small application"? Is this an add-on? Create a [mcve] and add it to the question.